# Problem running the Lux library - Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble running the Lux library on my Notebook.

I've tried following the instructions on their README file and looked for answers on Stack, nothing.

Here are my inputs and outputs:

**Input 1:**

```
!pip install lux-api
!jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
!jupyter labextension install luxwidget
```

**Output 1:**

```
Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
```

**Input 2:**

```
!jupyter nbextension install --py luxwidget
!jupyter nbextension enable --py luxwidget
```

**Output 2:**

```
Installing (...) 
Traceback (...) 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'
Enabling notebook extension luxwidget/extension...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X luxwidget/extension
```

**Input 3:**

```
from pydataset import data
import pandas as pd
import lux
```

**Input 4:**

```
df = data('iris')
df
```

**Output 4:**

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir0kX.png)

[Empty output after pressing the toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIMKH.png)

P.s.: I have Node.JS installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that lux relies on the `/usr/local/share/jupyter` folder.

My solution was to create a new folder with

```sh
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/jupyter
```

After, I changed the permissions with

```sh
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/jupyter
```

For me, there is not a problem to give access to this folder to other users.

After this, I executed the following two commands:

```sh
jupyter nbextension install --py luxwidget
jupyter nbextension enable --py luxwidget
```

If you used with *conda*, you want to execute

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install luxwidget
```

Some information was extracted from [Lux](https://github.com/lux-org/lux)

Comment: My bad, I fixed it.